# php using the modulos in if elseif and else statement

Tags: php

this is my problem im writing a code that will return the word "Fizz" if the number is divisble by 3 and "Buzz" if it divisible by 5. And "FizzBuzz" if the number is both divisible by 3 and 5.
here is my code

*

```
<?php
function fizzbuzz(i)
   if $i % 5 == 0 and $i % 3 == 0
     echo "FizzBuzz";
elsif $i % 5 == 0
     echo "Buzz";
elsif $i % 3 == 0
     echo "Fizz";
else
echo $i;
?>
```

*

Comment: You forgot `$` sign in your input argument. change to $i instead of i. Also you have syntax errors in your if statements

Comment: That's not even valid PHP code. You also forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I see a function...but not the {}. And @user3344741 what's your problem ? (any, the first, any error message will help).

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces aren't evil, Use them all the time, it will help you debug more easy and faster and save you valuable headache and annoying bugs.

**Code:** (Of course for this to actually work, you will need a wrapper while to use this function)

```
<?php

    function fizzbuzz(i) {
        if ($i%5 == 0 && $i%3 == 0) {
            echo "FizzBuzz";
        }
        elsif ($i%5 == 0) {
            echo "Buzz";
        }
        elsif ($i%3 == 0) {
            echo "Fizz";
        }
        else {
            echo $i;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the code you provide is not valid PHP code and you do not actually formulate a question about what you need help with, I will attempt to address your post in a very generalized way that is as helpful and as objective as possible.

FizzBuzz problems are meant to get you to think. Their intent isn't to answer the question. Anyone with a medial understanding of math and any computer programming language could answer a FizzBuzz question.

Instead, revel in the expression of the solution using code. Code, much like poetry, is meant to be beautiful, because while it is meant to be *run by machines* it is also meant to be **read by humans**.

Here is a more expressive and elegant way of putting down the same solution in valid PHP code.

```
function fizzBuzz($int) {
    /**
    *  Since this is a function we want to return a value and not print it.
    *  So instead we initialize a variable to return the result.
    */
    $returnValue = ""; // initialize an empty string

    /* Create a map of divisors to words */
    $divisors = array(3 => "Fizz", 5 => "Buzz");

    /* Iterate over the map to find divisors of no remainder for $int */
    foreach ($divisors as $divisor => $word) {
        if (!($int % $divisor)) {
            $returnValue .= $word;
        }
    }

    /* Finally, if the $returnValue is empty we return $int instead */
    if (!$returnValue) {
        $returnValue = $int;
    }

    return $returnValue;
}
```

The code is designed to be portable and easy to understand. It's also designed to be elegant in the sense that adding more divisors and words does not require additional lines of code. Just append the *divisor => word* pair in the `$divisor` array. Also, remember that functions should return values, rather than just blantantly print them for you. That's a part of what makes [functions](http://php.net/language.functions) useful.

Here's an example of how to use the function.

```
echo fizzBuzz(1); // 1
echo fizzBuzz(3); // Fizz
echo fizzBuzz(5); // Buzz
echo fizzBuzz(15); // FizzBuzz
```